# how to get React / Next js component file as text

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to convert my react/next js component file to text.

let a.jsx

```
"use client"

import { useState } from "react"

const Test = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1)
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between bg-red-500 ">
      <span>{number}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setNumber(number + 1)
        }}
      >
        increment
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Test
```

when the user clicks on show code for some component I want to show the exact file. with all import and hooks and etc